# Why "select * from emp as newemp; " got error in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to test rename (p) to make all same but only different table name, like Pnewemp (emp).

So I wrote

```
select * 
from emp as newemp
```

in Oracle but it did not work.

```
select empno as newempno 
from emp;
```

does work.

Please give me some advice.

Comment: Please give some details. "Doesn't work" isn't helpful. What error messages do you get?

Comment: In Oracle, the `AS` keyword is forbidden before a table alias. In ANSI/ISO SQL standard, the `AS` keyword is optional before a table alias so some RDBMS allow it; Oracle does not and forbids it.

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle,

- table alias doesn't support `as` keyword
- column alias does, but it isn't required

---

Table alias with an `as`:

```
SQL> select * from dept as newdept;
select * from dept as newdept
                   *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Table alias without `as`:

```
SQL> select * from dept newdept;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON
```

Combination:

```
SQL> select deptno as dno, dname department_name from dept newdept;
                   --            ----                      -------
    column's alias with AS       without AS             table alias without AS

       DNO DEPARTMENT_NAM
---------- --------------
        10 ACCOUNTING
        20 RESEARCH
        30 SALES
        40 OPERATIONS

SQL>
```

Comment: then if i only change table name, column name is not changed? like dname -> newdept_dname

Comment: We're talking about **aliases** here. Nothing is really changed (in the database), you're just giving column and/or table a "new name", i.e. alias. That's just like syt6180 - that's your alias on Stack Overflow; it isn't your real name, and - once you chose it as your alias, it didn't change your real name. The same goes with columns' and tables' aliases.